# Working on Jest with timers for vee validate

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, nuxt.js, vue-test-utils, vee-validate

I am trying to determine if my button is disabled but the `disabled` property keeps returning undefined. I have checked and followed the instruction in https://logaretm.github.io/vee-validate/advanced/testing.html#testing-validationobserver-debounced-state but it does not work accordingly. I think it is the way I implemented the Jest mock timers. Below is my code

```
import { mount, createLocalVue } from "@vue/test-utils";
import { ValidationObserver, ValidationProvider } from "vee-validate";
import { BootstrapVue } from "bootstrap-vue";
import Login from "@/pages/login.vue";

const localVue = createLocalVue();
localVue.component("ValidationObserver", ValidationObserver);
localVue.component("ValidationProvider", ValidationProvider);
localVue.use(BootstrapVue);

jest.useFakeTimers();

describe("Login", () => {
  test("if username is not entered", () => {
    const wrapper = mount(Login, { localVue });
    const username = wrapper.find("#username");
    const password = wrapper.find("#password");
    const login = wrapper.find("#login");
    jest.advanceTimersByTime(50);
    username.element.value = "test";
    password.element.value = "test";
    expect(login.attributes("disabled")).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

Basically, the behaviour of my login form is.. The login button is disabled until the user enters a value on the username and password inputs.

I am also using NuxtJS for this

Answer (score 1):

You would still need to wait for pending promises as well as using `flush-promises`. The docs suggest doing both as a part of a custom flush method.

```js
async function flush() {
  await flushPromises();
  jest.runAllTimers();
}
```